# Reversing a few tag synonyms to better match current search capabilities

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-management

As [SE search has been improved to be not as "accent/decoration sensitive"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21021/8348), it would seem to be  currently be more appropriate to use, for example, "Godel" on the site than the more "technically correct" "Goedel" (of course, "Gödel" should win, but this is a bit beside the point in the current discussion).

Because of this, I am thinking that it might be appropriate to reverse a few tag synonyms (some of which, admittedly, I created). Essentially, these are the ones where the master is "technically correct" but doesn't match up with SE's current search capabilities, whereas there are "faults" with the synonym, but the synonym would yield an "equivalent" search term.

For example, note that while searching for 
["Gödel incompleteness"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22G%C3%B6del%20incompleteness%22) 
and 
["Godel incompleteness"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Godel%20incompleteness%22) bring up the same results, searching for ["Goedel incompleteness"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Goedel%20incompleteness%22) brings up a disjoint set of results (except for posts which use both types). Therefore a hypothetical tag synonym [goedel-incompleteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goedel-incompleteness)⇒[godel-incompleteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godel-incompleteness)<sup>*</sup> should be preferable over [godel-incompleteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godel-incompleteness)⇒[goedel-incompleteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goedel-incompleteness), because an "equivalent" search term would appear in question pages.

The following is the list of tag synonyms I propose to reverse:

- [mobius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transformation)⇒[moebius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-transformation)
- [mobius-inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-inversion)⇒[moebius-inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-inversion)
- [mobius-band](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-band)⇒[moebius-band](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-band)
- [mobius-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-function)⇒[moebius-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-function)
- [kahler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kahler-manifolds)⇒[kaehler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaehler-manifolds)

(I am uncertain if [limits-without-lhopital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhopital)⇒[limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital) belongs to the same category, and would welcome input on this.)

So, does anyone have any strong opinions on this?

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>In case it's not obvious, my notation here is [synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym)⇒[master](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master).</sub>

Comment: It hurts to see "Godel" or "Mobius", but practical considerations win here, I support it.

Comment: Wait, are you suggesting to inverse the mobius inversion tag synonym?

Comment: I just wish they would implement accented characters in tag name... (Yeah I know they're using completely horrible hacks for tags, but still.)

Comment: @Najib: And then I won't be able to tag properly with ease.

Comment: @Asaf The unaccented versions could remain as a synonym of the accented one.

Comment: Just to see whether I understand this correctly: The direction of the synonym does not influence which questions are obtained when searching. But the master tag is, at the moment, less optimal phrase for searching. Is this correct?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes. Searching for `[mobius-transformation]` and `[moebius-transformation]` will return the same results because of the synonym (and it doesn't matter which way that synonym points). But searching for `"Mobius transformation"` and "`Moebius transformation"` will yield drastically different results, and only the former will match up with `"Möbius transformation"`.

Comment: [tag:teichmuller-theory] ⇒ [tag:teichmueller-theory] falls in this category as well: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31059

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the reversal, including the one about limits-without-lhopital.

Tested with Google search: a query such as "limit of sin(x)/x without l'hospital's rule" gets remapped to "limit of sin(x)/x without lhopital's rule"; and if one insists on searching for l'hospital's, the number of results from math.stackexchange.com drops by about 50%.