# List of commonly misspelled words

Tags: discussion, editing, spelling

Judging by some of the posts on meta<sup>1</sup> and comments posted there it seems that there are users who try to improve the posts by correcting spelling mistakes. Of course, there are other ways to improve the posts via editing, some of them probably more important than grammar and spelling.<sup>2</sup> Still this is certainly an improvement, a post with correct spelling is easier to read and using English correctly also increases the professional appearance of this site. Moreover, it helps with searching. (Posts which contain only the misspelled form of the words are less likely to be found when searching.)

Maybe it could be useful to *collect some commonly misspelled words*. This could make it easier for users, who have some spare time and want to do a few such edits, to find posts which have this problem.

For this reason it might be useful also include link to a search (or a [SEDE query](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info)) which returns those posts. Some minor comments on searching:

- For some words, the search also returns posts which contain minor variants of the words. Since we are searching for misspellings, in such cases adding quotation marks might help to find the misspelled ones. (For example, searching for [occurence](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=occurence) returns many results, but we are more interested in the ones which are found when we search for ["occurence"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q="occurence") and ["occurences"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q="occurences").)
- A simple SEDE query searching for some string can return words which contain this string as a some part. So sometimes we might want to look only at results containing exactly the given word. (Compare the results [searching for teh](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=banch?num=5000&text=teh) with the results where [teh is preceded and followed by a non-letter](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=teh)).
- It is better to use case insensitive version of SEDE queries. (So that we catch also misspelled word at the beginning of a sentence. This is especially important for names.)
- With SEDE you can find several words which contain the same substring. For example, words containing "anali" might often be typos (such as analisis, analise, analitic, etc.} and you can search for [anali](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=anali).

A few comments about editing the misspellings. (Some of them apply to editing in general.)

- It is better to avoid [bumping too many old posts at the same time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much). (Frontpage is considered a precious commodity.)
- For this reason it is better to concentrate on questions which are new or have been recently bumped for some other reason.
- If you edit some post, try to check whether there are also other improvements to do. (Since the post was bumped by correcting the misspelled word, it is better to improve also other things which are worth editing than to bump the same post by additional edits later.)
- Difference between British/American spelling should not be considered a misspelling, as discussed before: [Is English (US) vs English (UK) grounds for an edit?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30335)

Some names of mathematicians which are commonly misspelled can also be found in this answer: [Searching for accented characters is too strict](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8698#8709). (Although that answer is primarily about alternative spellings.) This might also help when creating list of common misspellings.

<sup>1</sup>Posts such as: [Edit session for wrong spelling of mathematicians and mathematical concepts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13730) or
[Wrong spelling of “occurrence”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30912). Some users have mentioned in chat that they do this kind of edits, for example, [Srivatsan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2443651#2443651).

<sup>2</sup>Just to name a few common problems with posts on this site which could be helped by editing: [non-descriptive titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144), incorrectly tagged question, various problems with MathJax in the post or [in the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles), etc. (Still, I'd guess that posts with misspellings are slightly more likely to have also some other problems - so perhaps checking them from time to time might be useful also for other purposes.)

<sup>3</sup>These SEDE queries are more for people who are curious (since they do not actually help with editing), but they still might be interesting anyway. You can find [posts where a specific word has already been corrected](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157683/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-case-in?word=haussdorff). You can also search in comments [for some string](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/556789/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author?Word=occurence) or for [an exact word](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157639/comments-containing-exact-string-with-text-and-author?text=teh).

Comment: "With SEDE you can find several words which contain the same substring."  aka Scunthorpe problem.

Comment: As always, your dedication to keeping things organized and your skills with SEDE are invaluable.  Thank you, @MartinSleziak.

Comment: It seems that we're already running into limit for the length of an answer, see [this conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/editing-the-list-of-common-misspellings-on-meta). Maybe this is an indication that meta is not really suitable for this purpose. Or maybe it just shows that I have included in the list some misspellings which aren't really that common.

Comment: Following the exchange in chat linked in the above comments, I have split the existing answer into two separate post. (Still, running into the character limit might be considered as an indication that maybe this is not a great idea or that it should be done differently.)

Answer (score 24):

Here are some words which have been misspelled in some posts on the site, also some SEDE queries are included.<sup>1</sup>

- alegbra; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=alegbra)
- analisis; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=analisis)
- analyis; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=analyis)
- aplication; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?q=aplication)
- asyptotic; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=asyptotic)
- Banch; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=banch)
- biyective; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=biyective)
- boudary; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=boudary)
- Caley; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=caley)
- caracteristic; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=caracteristic)
- Cauchy+Swartz; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=cauchy+swartz), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157669/posts-containing-two-given-words-case-insensitive?text1=cauchy&text2=swartz)
- Cauchy+Shwartz; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=cauchy+shwartz), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157669/posts-containing-two-given-words-case-insensitive?text1=cauchy&text2=shwartz)
- Cauchy+Schwartz; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=cauchy+schwartz), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157669/posts-containing-two-given-words-case-insensitive?text1=cauchy&text2=schwartz)
- choosen; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=choosen)
- compacness; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?q=compacness)
- conjecutre; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=conjecutre)
- continity; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=continity)
- continuty; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=continuty)
- continous; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=continous)
- continus; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=continus)
- continuos; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=continuos)
- Cuachy; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=cuachy)
- definiton; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=definiton)
- defintion; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=defintion)
- defition; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=defition)
- defnition; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=defnition)
- deriative; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=deriative)
- deriavtive; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=deriavtive)
- deriviative; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=deriviative)
- derteminant; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=derteminant)
- derterminant; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=derterminant)
- dervative; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?q=dervative)
- diferent; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=diferent)
- diffrent; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=diffrent)
- Eluer; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=eluer)
- exercice; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=exercice)
- finte; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=finte)
- fintely; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=fintely)
- fucntion; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=fucntion)
- funcion; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=funcion)
- fundemental; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=fundemental)
- funtion; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=funtion)
- Haussdorff; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=haussdorff)
- Hausdorf; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=hausdorf), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=hausdorf)
- inegral; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=inegral)
- inegration; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=inegration)
- ineqality; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=ineqality)
- ineqaulity; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=ineqaulity)
- infnity; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=infnity)
- integal; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=integal)
- integation; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=integation)
- integtal; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=integtal)
- intergal; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intergal)
- intergral; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intergral)
- intergate; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intergate)
- intergrate; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intergrate)
- intervall; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intervall)
- invaraint; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=invaraint)
- inyective; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=inyective)
- Kirchoff; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=kirchoff)
- Lapace; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=lapace)
- Laplce; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=laplce)
- Lebegue; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=lebegue)
- Lebesque; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=lebesque)
- Lebesue; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=lebesue)
- mathemaic; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=mathemaic)
- mathemaical; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=mathemaical)
- matrice; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22matrice%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=matrice)
- Mclaurin; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=mclaurin)
- Minkowsky; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=minkowsky)
- miminum; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=miminum)
- minimun; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=minimun)
- mininum; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=mininum)
- miniscule; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?q=miniscule)
- minumum; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=minumum)
- Neuman; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=neuman)
- notrivial; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=notrivial)
- occurence; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22occurence%22)
- ocurrence; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22ocurrence%22)
- paralel; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22paralel%22)
- patrial; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=patrial)
- polinomial; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=polinomial)
- polinomyal; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=polinomyal)
- poynomial; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=poynomial)
- proble; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=proble), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=proble)
- proofed; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22proofed%22)
- quare; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=quare), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=quare)
- represetnation; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=represetnation)
- Reiman; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=reiman)
- Reimann; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=reimann)
- Rieman; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=rieman), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=rieman)
- Shwartz; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=shwartz)
- subsitution; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=subsitution)
- substract; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=substract)
- suryective; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=suryective)
- teh; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=teh), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=teh)
- theorm; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=theorm)
- thinnk; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=thinnk)
- toplogy; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=toplogy)
- ultrafiler; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=ultrafiler)
- ultrafiter; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=ultrafiter)
- utrafilter; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=utrafilter)
- varition; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=varition)
- vertice; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22vertice%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=vertice)
- Weirstrass; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22Weirstrass%22)
- Wierstrass; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22Wierstrass%22)
- Weierstrauss; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22Weierstrauss%22)
- whit; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=whit), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=whit)

<sup>1</sup>There is character limit on the length of the post, to save space the SEDE queries are left only in the cases where *exact* search is needed and in cases where you search for *multiple* strings. You can easily modify SEDE query by changing parameter in the link, here is query for [algebra](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=alegbra). Notice that this query simply searches whether the post contains the given string - in cases when the word can be a substring of a different word, you should use [a different query](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?text=rieman). (You want to find posts containing the word Rieman, but not the word Riemann - which would be among the search results if you used the first query.)

Comment: The answer is [community wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info), feel free to editi it further if you have some additions and corrections.

Comment: Although `Proof that` is grammatically valid in some circumstances, I noticed that almost all of it should be replaced with `Prove that`. Just a note, I don't think it should be added to the list.

Comment: I agree with @KemonoChen that it's better not to add that to the post (since some false positives are quite likely). I will add at least in a comment link to [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22proof+that%22) and link to [case insensitive](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=proof%20that) and [case sensitive](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157427/search-for-exact-string?text=Proof%20that) version of the SEDE query. (Perhaps at the beginning of a sentence this is more likely a mistake.)

Comment: Should "Schwartz" really be on the list ? It seems to me that the most frequent error is people talking about "Cauchy-Schwartz inequality" ([been there, done that](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1834362/revisions)), but "Schwartz" alone can be OK.

Comment: @ArnaudD. That's a good point, especially considering that there are a few things named after [Laurent Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Schwartz). I removed it from the list.

Comment: morophism has it's own has it's own post about it as some suggest it's a way to get around duplicates.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Did you mean this post: [Misspelled titles to avoid duplicate titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30570)? I have included links to searches for posts containing morophi. (And I should change the queries in the way so that they also search titles, not only bodies - when I have a bit of times, I will go through the queries used in the post and replace them.)

Comment: I was thinking of mentioning *Lebesque* with a comment, but then I saw it listed, and decided to comment anyway. I've seen "Lebesgue" spelled as "Lebesque" throughout the mathematical literature going back for many decades, both in published papers and (to a lesser extent) in books. This has always struck me as very strange because Lebesgue's name VERY well known and it appears all over in mathematics and it also isn't like [Chebyshev's name](https://mathoverflow.net/q/167849/15780) which is [famous for it's many and varied non-misspelled versions](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0156901404).

Comment: @Dave see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433899/why-is-lebesgue-so-often-spelled-lebesque

Comment: @Roddy https://www.grammarly.com/blog/its-vs-its/

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Surprisingly, I had not seen this question before. And speaking of surprises, I'm especially surprised at the number of people who had never seen this spelling in a publication. I've personally seen this many times, even long before the internet (especially in Eastern Bloc journals and AMS translations of Russian journals). As for errors NOT introduced by a printer/typist/publisher, I also find this surprising, because just in class note taking and writing homework proofs, I'd written "Lebesgue" many hundreds of times by the time I was a second year graduate student.

Comment: Incidentally, the fairly prolific but lesser known mathematician V.-A. Lebesgue [is not immune to this misspelling](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/ldESLaV7YD4), although this is not a published example. In fact, I don't think I've ever seen V.-A. Lebesgue's name spelled as "Lebesque" in an actual published paper or book. You probably know both these examples, but like the well known math historian [Moritz Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moritz_Cantor), V.-A. Lebesgue has the unfortunate fate of have the same surname as a MUCH more famous mathematician.

Comment: @Dave, I remember coming across a printed reference to a paper by M. Lebesgue and being confused because I knew the paper was by V.-A. Lebesgue. Eventually I decided that the M in M. Lebesgue was the abbreviation of Monsieur!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: For 1800s and early 1900s literature, I've learned to mistrust any 'M' used in front of an author's name. It usually means "Monsieur", but I've seen a few exceptions (don't know any offhand, however). Note that in [this answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/158070/15780), this usage of 'M' appears in Denjoy **[2]**, Khinchin **[1]**, and Luzin **[2]**. Of course, these authors a sufficiently well known that there is no reasonable chance of being mistaken. More care needs to be taken, for example, with some of [these authors](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2780697/13130).

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: *don't know any offhand* --- Here's an example. Maurice Fouché (1855-1929) is the author cited as "M. Fouché" on .pdf page 21 [here](https://archive.org/details/revuesemestriel04unkngoog/page/n20) (Vol. 4 (1896) of **Revue Semestrielle des Publications Mathématiques**). Also [.pdf p. 226](https://archive.org/details/revuesemestriel04unkngoog/page/n226) of the same document, and see [this google books result](https://books.google.com/books?id=7G1aAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false) also. However, this might not really count, because the other names non-M first initials.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's is for it is or it has I know, I looked it up. I just can't seem to use them consistently.

Comment: pimitive and quare are ones I've edited recently.

Comment: "monotonous" is often used where "monotonic" is meant.

Comment: I added "miniscule" ... but do we want to include words like this which are already commonly misspelled in general English?

Comment: @GEdgar I have to admit that I did not know that [miniscule](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miniscule) is misspelling. Regarding the question whether or not it should be included - but I don't see any harm, it's up to users who actually use this list whether or not they decide to use this particular link. (And moreover, since it is CW, if somebody feels strongly about this, they can edit the word away - the same goes for some other words.)

Comment: I take it we're not trying to distinguish between misspelling and typographical error.

Comment: Should we include [plz](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=plz) and [thnx](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=thnx) in this list? If yes, IMO should be changed to _please_ and _thanks_ and not to remove them

Answer (score 7):

Some examples of **incorrect possessive:**

Stoke's theorem (incorrect) should be Stokes' or even Stokes's since the man's name is "Stokes".

Similar: Baye's theorem (incorrect), which appeared somewhere in .se recently.

Descarte's Rule of Signs

Comment: Gaus's here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159270/gauss-multiplication

Comment: Putting Descarte's before the hor'se. I think, therefore I'm.

Comment: Apparently Stokes's vs Stokes' is a matter of style; the AP style guide has the latter whereas the CMS has the former. https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/style.html

Answer (score 2):

Strings which most likely appear in the words which are
misspelled:

- alegb*; SEDE [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=alegb), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=alegb)
- anali*; SEDE [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=anali), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=anali)
- anay*; SEDE [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=anay), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=anay)
- ananl*; SEDE [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=ananl), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=ananl)
- assymp*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=assymp), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=assymp)
- asypto*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=asypto), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=asypto)
- caracter*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=caracter), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=caracter)
- contino*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=contino), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=contino)
- defint*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=defint), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=defint)
- definito*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=definito), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=definito)
- defni*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=defni), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=defni)
- deriav*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=deriav), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=deriav)
- difer*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=difer), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=difer)
- evalau*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=evalau), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=evalau)
- fucn*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=fucn), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=fucn)
- funcion*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=funcion), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=funcion)
- funtion*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=funtion), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=funtion)
- intega*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=intega), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=intega)
- integt*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=integt), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=integt)
- interg*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=interg), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=interg)
- mimin*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=mimin), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=mimin)
- minum*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=minum),
  [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=minum)
- polino*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=polino), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=polino)
- subsit*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=subsit), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=subsit)
- toplog*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=toplog), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=toplog)
- varit*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=varit), [beginning](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157688/search-for-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=varit)
- *morophism; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=morophism), [end](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1158167/search-for-string-at-the-end-of-a-word-case-insensitive?text=morophism)
- *morophi*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=morophi)
- *finte*; SEDE: [anywhere](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157659/posts-containing-a-given-text-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=finte)

Phrases (consisting of more than one word) which might often indicate a mistake or misspelling:

- a dice; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22a+dice%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=a%20dice)
- Baye's theorem; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22baye%27s+theorem%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=baye%27%27s%20theorem)
- I thing; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22I+thing%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=i%20thing)
- linear application; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22linear+application%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=linear%20application)
- Stoke's theorem; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22stoke%27s+theorem%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=stoke%27%27s%20theorem)
- to proof; [search](//math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%22to+proof%22), [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1157664/search-for-exact-string-case-insensitive?num=5000&text=to%20proof)

Comment: Martin, I have notice that you included GEdgar suggestions in the _Phrases_ section. Also, in the _Strings_ section is "funcion" and "funtion" which is already considered on your other answer